# if((result=f())==0) is Undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

> #### 5.17 Assignment Operators
>
> There are several assignment operators, all of which group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand, and the type of an assignment expression is that of its left operand. The result of the assignment operation is the value stored in the left operand after the assignment has taken place; the result is an lvalue.

#### Question

- `if((result=f())==0)`, is it *undefined-behavior* ?

Comment: Don't get it. Should it be? Variable 'result' is the lvalue, the return value of f() is assigned to it and the if statement compares it with 0. Looks fine to me. Maybe you could point out your question a little more?

Comment: There is only 1 assignment operator there

Comment: Wait, is this C++ or C? You have a C tag, but quote the C++ standard...

Comment: The quote from the (C++) standard is identifying that there is the simple assignment (`=`) operator, and various compound assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`, etc).  It is not being claimed that there are multiple assignment operators in the condition `if ((result = f()) == 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

In C, the equality operator `==` is not the same thing as two assignment operators. Thus in the statement `if((result=f())==0){...}` there is only a single assignment operator hence the part of the C standard that addresses expressions with multiple assignment operators is simply not relevant. This particular expression is perfectly defined (assuming `f()` is).

The somewhat similar expression `while((c = getchar()) != EOF){···}` is a fairly common idiom for grabbing keyboard input character by character until the end of file character is encountered. Such idioms allow you to kill two birds with one stone -- assign a value to a variable while simultaneously comparing that value with another value.

Comment: assuming `x`  is `int`. Is `x=x=x=x=x;` undefined behavior?

Comment: @AngelusMortis: no because its equivalent to `x=(x=(x=(x=x)))`, so each assignment is dependent on the following assignment and so they occur right to left.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That doesn't make it well defined. Assigning to the same object multiple times without an intervening sequence point yields undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.. Per 6.5 paragraph 1 in the C spec, "The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator."  So each assignment is sequenced after the assignment that it gets its value from, and the behavior is well-defined.

Comment: Hm, that language is new in C11. Not clear yet on how it's intended to be interpreted and whether its a new feature, but I'm rather confident this was UB in C99 and earlier.

Comment: @R.. C99 defintely went overboard in making things undefined that were formerly somewhat-defined.  The perils of post-facto standardization.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Citation needed. My experience reading both standards is quite the opposite: C99 defined some things that were previously undefined. It was just that people used to ignore the fact that they were undefined... I said *and earlier* specifically because this particular case was also UB in the original C standard (C89).